Подтягивается старая версия npm-пакета в VSCode
Работаю в VisualStudio Code. Устанавливаю пакет из корпоративного репозитория:
npm install npi_test. Проверяю физическое наличие пакета в папке с проектом в node_modules - пакет установился, нужной версии с правильным содержимым. Запускается проект, и на странице вижу СТАРЫЕ данные из пакета, которого уже нет в node_modules!!!
Погуглил, пишут, что нужно почистить кэш nmm командой npm cache clean --force. Выполняю, перекомпилирую проект, запускаю - то же самое. Откуда то подтягиваются старые данные пакета, которого давно уже нет в node_modules. Что за чертовщина вообще?

возможно одна из используемых библиотек имеем в зависимостях устаревшую версию пакета. просмотрите package-lock.json вручную

Добрый день. Спасибо за комментарий, но package-lock.json я:

полностью удалял перед установкой пакета.
смотрел на предмет npi_test - этого пакета там не было перед установкой.


Да, ещё - ПОЛНОСТЬЮ удалял папку node_modules и делал npm install.
Затем проверил ещё раз наличие npi_test - всё есть. правильная версия, содержимое верное.
Подключаю его в import, проверяю, проваливаясь по ссылке. Пакет правильный!
Запускаю проект - данные на странице от старого пакета, который непонятно откуда берется. ((
